# How to insert data into List<Map<String,dynamic>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

So i got an error said that "The argument type 'Map<String, Object>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<Map<String, dynamic>>" which im trying to pass my textfield data into the list. The problem is at the function call void addItemtoList() can anyone help me with this problem heres the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'contactDetail.dart';


class ContactList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ContactList> createState() => _ContactListState();
}

class _ContactListState extends State<ContactList> {

  final dateStr = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now());

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allUsers = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Andy", "age": "29"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Aragon", "age": "40"},
  ];
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();

  void addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      _allUsers.addAll({
        "id":1,
        "name":nameController.text,
        "age":phoneController.text}
      );


    });
  }
  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _foundUsers = [];
  @override
  initState() {

    _foundUsers = _allUsers;
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = _allUsers;
    } else {
      results = _allUsers
          .where((user) =>
          user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }
    setState((){
      _foundUsers = results;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Search Listview'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Name',
                ),
              ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            TextField(
              controller: phoneController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Phone',
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Expanded(
              child: _foundUsers.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _foundUsers.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                  key: ValueKey(_foundUsers[index]["id"]),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  elevation: 4,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: Text(
                      _foundUsers[index]["id"].toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color:Colors.white),
                    ),
                    title: Text(_foundUsers[index]['name'], style:TextStyle(
                        color:Colors.white
                    )),
                    subtitle: Text(
                        '${_foundUsers[index]["age"].toString()} years old',style:TextStyle(
                        color:Colors.white
                    )),
                  ),
                ),
              )
                  : const Text(
                'No results found',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of call `addAll` use `add`:

```
_allUsers.add({
    "id":1,
    "name":nameController.text,
    "age":phoneController.text}
  );
```

`addAll` used when you want add list of something.